# Autoclicker Visual studio CS

Tags: c#

I tried to make my own autoclicker. Everything went fine.
[image: The ui started as you can see]

But when i press the button it only changes status from off to on.. but nothing happens.

I tried very long time to check for errors but i didnt find any.
This is my script so if you find any errors please tell me!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace BetaClicker
{
    public partial class form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport(dllName:"user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int cButtons, int dwExtraInfo);

        private const int LEFTUP = 0x0004;
        private const int LEFTDOWN = 0x0002;

        public form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void clicktimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int maxcps = (int)Math.Round(1000.0 / (trackBar1.Value + trackBar2.Value * 0.2));
            int mincps = (int)Math.Round(1000.0 / (trackBar1.Value + trackBar2.Value * 0.4));
            try
            {
                clicktimer.Interval = rnd.Next(mincps, maxcps);
            }
            catch
            {
                //Ignored
            }


            bool mousdown = MouseButtons == MouseButtons.Left;
            if (mousdown)
            {
                mouse_event(dwFlags:LEFTDOWN, dx:0,dy:0,cButtons:0,dwExtraInfo:0);
                Thread.Sleep(millisecondsTimeout: rnd.Next(1, 6));
                mouse_event(dwFlags: LEFTUP, dx: 0, dy: 0, cButtons: 0, dwExtraInfo: 0);
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (button1.Text.Contains("on"))
            {
                clicktimer.Start();
                button1.Text = "Toggle: off";
            }
            else
            {
                clicktimer.Stop(); 
                button1.Text = "Toggle: on";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you mean by auto clicker ? what you are trying to do ?

Comment: a gui with a button. and when you press that button it will start spamclicking

Comment: @robiot did you take a look at my answer? Did it solve your problem?

Comment: yes i did Giovanni... but it still didnt work :()

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to change the portion of code where you click with the following:

```
int X = Cursor.Position.X;
int Y = Cursor.Position.Y;
mouse_event(LEFTDOWN | LEFTUP, X, Y, 0, 0);
```

I think that your problem is that you start clicking but always in the position of the screen at the coordinates (0, 0) so nothing happens. 
Also you don't actually need a timeout from the LEFTDOWN action and the LEFTUP one

If you don't want to click where your cursor is just set `X` and `Y` with your desired values (coordinates)